# Generalization of Eisenstein's Criterion

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

> Let $f(X)=a_{2n+1}X^{2n+1}+\ldots+a_0\in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ with
> $$\begin{align*}
>  a_{2n+1}&\not \equiv 0 \pmod p\\
> a_{2n},\ldots,a_{n+1} &\equiv 0 \pmod p\\
> a_n,\ldots,a_0&\equiv 0 \pmod{p^2} \\
> \text{but } a_0&\not\equiv 0 \pmod{p^3}
> \end{align*}$$ Prove $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[X]$

Because the power is odd, we must have $f(X)=g(X)h(X)$ with different degrees. Suppouse without loss of generality that $\deg h=m>\deg g=r$. Let us fix the following notation: $g=\sum b_jX^j$ and $h=\sum u_j X^j$. Clearly $p\nmid b_r$ and $p\nmid u_m$.

If $p^2 $ divides the entire first coefficient of either $g$ or $h$ we get a contradiction identical to that of Eisenstein's original criterion.

Therefore, we must have $p|u_0$ and $p|b_0$. In this case let $k$ be the first such that $p\nmid u_k$ or $p\nmid b_k$. We have that the degree inequality implies $k\leq r\leq n<n+1\leq m$. Therefore $p^2|a_k$. On the other hand:

$$a_k=u_kb_0+...+u_0b_k\Rightarrow p^2| u_kb_0+u_0b_k$$

This implies $p|u_k (b_0/p)+(u_0/p)b_k$. The only way for this to happen is that $p\nmid u_k$ and $p\nmid b_k$.Therefore the first coefficient not divible by $p$ has the same accompanying degree in both $g$ and $h$. I am not sure how to draw a contradiction out of this.

**EDIT:** The point I didn't quite understand in the proof of the answer made me finish things off:

Taking the congruence modulo $p$ we have

$$\bar{a}_{2n+1}X^{2n+1}=\left(\sum_{j=k}^r\bar{b}_jX^j\right)\left(\sum_{j=k}^m \bar{u}_jX^j\right)$$

But that would imply $\bar{b}_k \bar{u}_k$ is the non zero term on the lefthandside. Therefore, $2k=2n+1$. But this is absurd!

Comment: I would probably reduce the problem without loss of generality to the case where $a_{2n+1} = b_r = u_m = 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is reducible over $\mathbb Q[X]$; since it's a polynomial in $\mathbb Z[X]$, it's reducible over $\mathbb Z[X]$. Then we can write (as in the proof of Eisenstein's condition)
$$f(X)=(uX^r+pg(X))(vX^s+ph(X))$$
for integers $u$ and $v$ not divisible by $p$, polynomials $g,h\in\mathbb Z[X]$, and $r+s=2n+1$. Let $g_0$ and $h_0$ be the unit coefficients of $g$ and $h$. Without loss of generality, suppose $r\leq s$; then $r\leq n$. We have
\begin{align*}
a_r=[X^r]f(X)
&=[X^r]\big(uvX^{r+s}+puX^rh(X)+pvX^sg(X)+p^2g(X)h(X)\big)\\
&\equiv puh_0\pmod{p^2}.
\end{align*}
Since $p^2\mid a_r$ as $r\leq n$, we conclude $p\mid h_0$. However,
$$a_0=[X^0]f(X)=p^2g_0h_0,$$
and so $p^3\mid a_0$, a contradiction.

Comment: Why do $g$ and $h$ have no factors of $p$ in the denominator?

Comment: @Kadmos If $f$ is reducible in $\mathbb Q[X]$, it's reducible in $\mathbb Z[X]$. Now, take such a factorization and divide both polynomials by their leading coefficients. Since the original leading coefficients multiply to $a_{2n+1}$, which is not a multiple of $p$, neither of the leading coefficients are multiples of $p$, so we introduce no factors of $p$ in the denominators we create.

Comment: Not sure I follow. I proved the first term non divisible by $p$ is the same in both of them. If $p$ divides all of the coefficients lower than $r$ and $s$ that doesn't follow I think. But maybe I am just tired. I will read your answer tomorrow again.

Comment: @Kadmos I've updated the answer to skip the step where coefficients are made monic: it was mostly for notational ease anyway.

Comment: Sorry. I thought I got it now. But I have the same doubt. Why does $p$ divide all coefficients smaller then $r$ and $s$? I think that cannot be the case, because the first term non divible has the same degree in both polynomials we are using to factor $f$.

Comment: @Kadmos Are you familiar with the standard proof of Eisenstein's criterion?

Comment: Sure. Take the lowest coefficient non divisible by $p$ and study $a_k$ to get a contradiction. I guess you have a different proof in mind. But I was able to finish my original line of reasoning (see the edit). I would love to understand your argument aswell though. But I guess since this is a duplicate it wouldn't be very good use of your time. But thank you anyways...